# HP Pavilion WiFi F12 button does not work after upgrade

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

I recently upgraded my system from Window 7 to Window 8.1. Everything seems to be working fine except that my HP Pavilion G6 WiFi <kbd>F12</kbd> button refuses to work. It suppose to work as a toggle. when I click it, it is supposed to enable wireless and show a white light. Then, on clicking it again, it should disable wireless card and show a red light. This behavior however is not working after the upgrade. It only shows the white light, the button doesn't turn off the wireless card. How do i fix this ?

Comment: It works if hold Fn button and then press F12?

Answer (score 2):

Hotkeys for most laptops require that you install the drivers for the buttons before they'll work properly. Sometimes the drivers for Windows 7 will work in Windows 8 just fine, but sometimes they do not.

You can obtain those drivers from the [HP support website](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/drivers.html).

Also you can check UEFI BIOS settings ([HP Laptop have BIOS options that can change behavior "F*" buttons.](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c02035108))